# Showing $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, given by $$ f(x) := \begin{cases} x^2 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ x^4 & x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases} $$ (a) Use $ε- δ$ definition of continuity to show that $f$ is continuous at $x=0.$
>
> (b) Show that $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 2$

Solution Attempt:

a) Given $ε > 0$, choose $δ = ε$. Then, if $|x| < δ = ε$, we have $|f(x) − f(0)| = |f(x)| = |x| < ε$ if $x$ is rational and$ |f(x) − f(0)| = 0 < ε$ if $x$ is irrational. In either case, $|x| < δ$ implies $|f(x) − f(0)| < ε$. This proves continuity at $x = 0$.

b) Let $x \neq 0$. Take a sequence ${x_n}$ of rationals converging to $x$. Then $f(x_n) = x_n → x$. Also take a sequence ${y_n}$ of irrationals converging to x. Then $f(y_n) = 0 → 0$. Since $x \neq 0$, it follows that the limit of $f$ at $x$ does not exist. Hence $f$ is not continuous at $x$.

Comment: $f(x) \ne x$, so your a is false. I guess you mean $ \mid f(x) \mid \leq \mid x \mid$

Comment: The solutions a, b are not consistent with the function.

Comment: Can somebody post solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

It is known that the only points where $f$ is continous are the solutions of the equation $x^4=x^2$
Hence,the only points where $f$ is continous are $x\in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Comment: Can you post full solution please?